# Android : How to put object on particular location of screen using openCv?

Tags: android, opencv3.1, opencv

**Edited:**

If anyone one can suggest any link or post, I will be very grateful. I am trying to find solution from two days and i can't find any.Thank you in advance.

---

I am trying to put one object(image) on particular location of screen Using openCv in android.

I do have Points like this "{680.0, 488.0}" which is having (x,y) coordinate,

So **how can I find particular location in my screen for putting object ?**

Below is my code where i am getting Point:

```
     public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray = inputFrame.gray();

        iThreshold = minTresholdSeekbar.getProgress();

        //Imgproc.blur(mRgba, mRgba, new Size(5,5));
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mRgba, mRgba, new org.opencv.core.Size(3, 3), 1, 1);
        //Imgproc.medianBlur(mRgba, mRgba, 3);

        if (!mIsColorSelected) return mRgba;

        List<MatOfPoint> contours = mDetector.getContours();
        mDetector.process(mRgba);

        Log.d(TAG, "Contours count: " + contours.size());

        if (contours.size() <= 0) {
            return mRgba;
        }

        RotatedRect rect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(0).toArray()));

        double boundWidth = rect.size.width;
        double boundHeight = rect.size.height;
        int boundPos = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < contours.size(); i++) {
            rect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(i).toArray()));
            if (rect.size.width * rect.size.height > boundWidth * boundHeight) {
                boundWidth = rect.size.width;
                boundHeight = rect.size.height;
                boundPos = i;
            }
        }

        Rect boundRect = Imgproc.boundingRect(new MatOfPoint(contours.get(boundPos).toArray()));
        //Core/Imgproc.rectangle( mRgba, boundRect.tl(), boundRect.br(), CONTOUR_COLOR_WHITE, 2, 8, 0 );

        Log.d(TAG,
                " Row start [" +
                        (int) boundRect.tl().y + "] row end [" +
                        (int) boundRect.br().y + "] Col start [" +
                        (int) boundRect.tl().x + "] Col end [" +
                        (int) boundRect.br().x + "]");

        int rectHeightThresh = 0;
        double a = boundRect.br().y - boundRect.tl().y;
        a = a * 0.7;
        a = boundRect.tl().y + a;

        Log.d(TAG,
                " A [" + a + "] br y - tl y = [" + (boundRect.br().y - boundRect.tl().y) + "]");

        //Core.rectangle( mRgba, boundRect.tl(), boundRect.br(), CONTOUR_COLOR, 2, 8, 0 );
        //Core/Imgproc.rectangle( mRgba, boundRect.tl(), new Point(boundRect.br().x, a), CONTOUR_COLOR, 2, 8, 0 );

        MatOfPoint2f pointMat = new MatOfPoint2f();
        Imgproc.approxPolyDP(new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(boundPos).toArray()), pointMat, 3, true);
        contours.set(boundPos, new MatOfPoint(pointMat.toArray()));

        MatOfInt hull = new MatOfInt();
        MatOfInt4 convexDefect = new MatOfInt4();
        Imgproc.convexHull(new MatOfPoint(contours.get(boundPos).toArray()), hull);

        if (hull.toArray().length < 3) return mRgba;

        Imgproc.convexityDefects(new MatOfPoint(contours.get(boundPos).toArray()), hull, convexDefect);

        List<MatOfPoint> hullPoints = new LinkedList<MatOfPoint>();
        List<Point> listPo = new LinkedList<Point>();
        for (int j = 0; j < hull.toList().size(); j++) {
            listPo.add(contours.get(boundPos).toList().get(hull.toList().get(j)));
        }

        MatOfPoint e = new MatOfPoint();
        e.fromList(listPo);
        hullPoints.add(e);

        List<MatOfPoint> defectPoints = new LinkedList<MatOfPoint>();
        List<Point> listPoDefect = new LinkedList<Point>();
        for (int j = 0; j < convexDefect.toList().size(); j = j + 4) {
            Point farPoint = contours.get(boundPos).toList().get(convexDefect.toList().get(j + 2));
            Integer depth = convexDefect.toList().get(j + 3);
            if (depth > iThreshold && farPoint.y < a) {
                listPoDefect.add(contours.get(boundPos).toList().get(convexDefect.toList().get(j + 2)));
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "defects [" + j + "] " + convexDefect.toList().get(j + 3));
        }

        MatOfPoint e2 = new MatOfPoint();
        e2.fromList(listPo);
        defectPoints.add(e2);

        Log.d(TAG, "hull: " + hull.toList());
        Log.d(TAG, "defects: " + convexDefect.toList());

        Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, hullPoints, -1, CONTOUR_COLOR, 3);

        int defectsTotal = (int) convexDefect.total();
        Log.d(TAG, "Defect total " + defectsTotal);

        this.numberOfFingers = listPoDefect.size();
        if (this.numberOfFingers > 5) {
            this.numberOfFingers = 5;
        } /*else if (this.numberOfFingers == 1) {
            this.numberOfFingers = 0;
        }
*/

        mHandler.post(mUpdateFingerCountResults);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ring.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                /*LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10,10);
                ring.setLayoutParams(parms);*/
            }
        });

        for (Point p : listPoDefect) {

            Log.e("Points", p.toString());
            // Imgproc.circle(mRgba, p, 6, new Scalar(255,0,255));
        }

        return mRgba;
    }
```

Below is the method which i have used to save image and display. **Now i need to put ring on one of captured hand fingers.**

```
   private void saveImage() {

    if (MainActivity.listPoDefect.size() >= 5) {
        mIsColorSelected = false;


        if (listPoDefect.size() != 0) {
            for (Point p :listPoDefect) {

                Log.d(TAG, "before sorting X =" + String.valueOf(p.x) + " Y = " + String.valueOf(p.y));

            }
            Collections.sort(listPoDefect, new Comparator<Point>() {

                public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
                    return Double.compare(o1.x, o2.x);
                }
            });


            Log.d(TAG, "After Sorting ");

            for (Point p : listPoDefect) {

                Log.d(TAG, "after sorting X =" + String.valueOf(p.x) + " Y = " + String.valueOf(p.y));

            }

        }


        mIsColorSelected = false;


        Bitmap bitmap5 = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgbaWithoutLine.cols(), mRgbaWithoutLine.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Utils.matToBitmap(mRgbaWithoutLine, bitmap5);


        bitmap = bitmap5;


        //Create a new image bitmap and attach a brand new canvas to it
        Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap5.getWidth(), bitmap5.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);

        //Draw the image bitmap into the cavas
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap5, 0, 0, null);


        double scaledWidth = bitmap5.getWidth();
        double scaledHeight = bitmap5.getHeight();

        double xScaleFactor = scaledWidth / bitmap5.getWidth();
        double yScaleFactor = scaledHeight / bitmap5.getHeight();


        Paint myRectPaint = new Paint();
        myRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        myRectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        myRectPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        myRectPaint.setAntiAlias(true);


       //this is zeroth position manipulation

        double differenceX= listPoDefect.get(2).x-listPoDefect.get(1).x;
        double differenceY= listPoDefect.get(2).y-listPoDefect.get(1).y;

        double zeroPostionX=listPoDefect.get(1).x-differenceX;
        double zeroPostionY=listPoDefect.get(1).y-differenceY;

        Point pointZeroths=listPoDefect.get(0);

        Point pointNew=new Point(zeroPostionX,zeroPostionY);

        listPoDefect.remove(0);

        listPoDefect.add(0,pointNew);


        double thirdPostionX=listPoDefect.get(2).x+differenceX;
        double thirdPostionY=listPoDefect.get(2).y+differenceY;

        Point thirdpointNew=new Point(thirdPostionX,thirdPostionY);

        listPoDefect.remove(3);

        listPoDefect.add(3,thirdpointNew);


        //    Point pointNewThird=new Point(pointthird.x+differenc,pointthird.y);


        //   HomeActivity.listPoDefect.remove(3);

        //   HomeActivity.listPoDefect.add(3,pointNewThird);

        Paint paint_text = new Paint();
        paint_text.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint_text.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint_text.setTextSize(30);

        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) { // draw 2 rows


            Point point1 = null;
            point1 = listPoDefect.get(row);


            android.graphics.Point canvas_point1 = new android.graphics.Point((int) ((point1.x * xScaleFactor)), (int) ((point1.y * yScaleFactor)));


            Log.d(TAG, "after sorting canvas_point1 ="+"Raw ="+row +" " + String.valueOf(canvas_point1.x) + " Y = " + String.valueOf(canvas_point1.y));
            Log.d(TAG, "====================================================================================================");

            if(pointFListGraphies.size()!=4)
            {
                pointFListGraphies.add(new PointF(canvas_point1));

            }
          // tempCanvas.drawRect(canvas_point1.x, canvas_point1.y, canvas_point1.x + 130, canvas_point1.y + 50, myRectPaint);

           // tempCanvas.drawText(String.valueOf(row+"-"+canvas_point1.x), canvas_point1.x, canvas_point1.y, paint_text);

        }
        Log.d(TAG, "====================================================================================================");


        for (int row = 0; row <  pointFListGraphies.size(); row++) { // draw 2 rows


            PointF point1 = null;
            point1 = pointFListGraphies.get(row);
            Log.d(TAG, "=========pointF X="+point1.x +"poninF Y =" +point1.y);

        }
        tempbitmap = tempBitmap;
        handImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        handImage.setImageBitmap(tempbitmap);
       /* Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ring);
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap();*/
        onCameraViewStopped();

        //finish();
    }
    else {

    }

}
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV has a number of functions for writing on an image, which is usually what you are displaying on the screen.

FOr example the function to write text a particular location is

```js
void cv::putText    (   InputOutputArray    img,
        const String &  text,
        Point   org,
        int     fontFace,
        double  fontScale,
        Scalar  color,
        int     thickness = 1,
        int     lineType = LINE_8,
        bool    bottomLeftOrigin = false 
)
```

The parameters are:

```js
Parameters
  img   Image.
  text  Text string to be drawn.
  org   Bottom-left corner of the text string in the image.
  fontFace  Font type, see cv::HersheyFonts.
  fontScale Font scale factor that is multiplied by the font-specific base      size.
  color Text color.
  thickness Thickness of the lines used to draw a text.
  lineType  Line type. See the line for details.
  bottomLeftOrigin  When true, the image data origin is at the bottom-left        corner. Otherwise, it is at the top-left corner.
```

You can find an overview of the drawing function here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html

In your case, so long as your image covers the whole screen this allows you plot exactly where you want the text, or object or whatever you want too draw to appear.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Mick. Let me describe more about my question. i want a ring to be placed on  one of fingers of my hand which I have captured using above code. Can you help for that ?

Comment: I you mean put a ring, like a wedding ring, on your finger then that is a much harder task as the image you will want to add will change as the orientation of the finger changes. I suspect that actually adding the image will be the easy part and the complexity will be in getting the finger alignment and creating the ring image to match it.

Comment: Yes @Mick That was i am saying, Task is like to put ring on any finger of hand. and after that ring should be movable from finger to finger on our touch. Got stuck from past few days..